# Query to check configuration properties of running QuestDB instance

Tags: questdb

I was wondering if there is a way to query QuestDB for its configuration properties through SQL. I have noticed meta functions to see tables and table columns.

Answer (score 0):

Querying config variables is not currently supported in the open source version